# how to create CVS repository and how to add users to it

Tags: cvs

I'm quite new to CVS. please anyone provide me steps(step-by-step) to create CVS repository and adding users to it in Linux environment. Thank you!!!

Comment: Is there any reason to use CVS? It is very serious outdated. You should consider Mercurial or at least Subversion for today projects.

Comment: well , as part of our project we are using CVS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CVS manual can be found here:

http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs.html

The Creating a repository section is here:

http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs_2.html#SEC23

That should get you started